# Why is object not considered so by the compiler?

Tags: scala, macros, enums

I tried gathering a sealed class's children:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Enum {
  def values[A]: Seq[A] = macro EnumImpl.values[A]

  class EnumImpl(val c: Context) {
    import c.universe._

    implicit class SymbolOp(s: Symbol) {
      def asSealedClass = s.asClass.ensuring(_.isSealed, s"$s is not sealed")
      def asCaseClass = s.asClass.ensuring(_.isCaseClass, s"$s is not a case class")
    }

    def values[A: c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[A] = {
      val enumSymbol = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.asSealedClass
      val elemSymbols = enumSymbol.knownDirectSubclasses.toList
      val elemIdents = elemSymbols.map(s => Ident(s.asCaseClass))
      val elemSeqSymbol = weakTypeOf[Seq[A]].typeSymbol
      c.Expr(Apply(Ident(elemSeqSymbol.companion), elemIdents))
    }
  }
}
```

I tested it with this:

```
sealed trait Foo
case object Moo extends Foo

println(Enum.values[Foo])
```

Then the compiler claims:

```
object Moo is not a value
```

So I tried its companion:

```
...
val elemIdents = elemSymbols.map(s => Ident(s.asCaseClass.companion))
...
```

Then the compiler claims:

```
not found: value <none>
```

So the object `Moo` is not an object XD

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This diagram from the [compiler code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Symbols.scala#L2172) describes the general situation with classes modules and module classes pretty well (internally objects are called modules):

```
The internal representation of classes and objects:

class Foo is "the class" or sometimes "the plain class"
object Foo is "the module"
class Foo$ is "the module class" (invisible to the user: it implements object Foo)

class Foo  <
^   ^ (2)   \
|   |  |     \
|  (5) |     (3)
|   |  |       \
(1) v  v        \
object Foo (4)-> > class Foo$

(1) companionClass
(2) companionModule
(3) linkedClassOfClass
(4) moduleClass
(5) companionSymbol
```

This stuff is all internal. However, it is important to see, that when you query the subclasses of your trait, you will get the module class and not the module itself.

You can get from the module class to the module by calling `module` on the module class symbol:

```
val elemIdents = for {
  elemSym <- elemSymbols
  if elemSym.isModuleClass // TODO fail if not a module class? Ignore?
} yield Ident(elemSym.asClass.module)
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED XD Thank you so much! I honestly don't understand the detail at the moment but... I will try :)

Comment: I got another quick question; `println(Enum.values[A])` works perfect, but `val v = values[A]; println(v)` prints out an empty list. How do you deal with this?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Are you sure you are compiling the macro in a separate compilation unit?

Comment: Yes, I think so... I tested it in other modules both inside and outside of the main project. My test is here: https://github.com/ryo0ka/enum/blob/master/enum-test/src/test/scala/enum/test/EnumTest.scala

Comment: Your test project doesn't depend on the normal project (besides, just putting stuff in `test` and not compile is sufficient). You probably declare the dependencies in IDEA, but IDEA cannot handle all macros. I doubt the issue is with your macro code here.

Comment: I made another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613776/macro-strange-action-wanting-a-better-title Could you answer there? Thanks :)