# Macro strange action (wanting a better title)

Tags: scala, macros

I've made an enum macro, which ended up having a strange behavior.

This is the main implementation:

```
object Enum {
  def values[A]: Seq[A] = macro Impl.values[A]

  class Impl(val c: Context) {
    import c.universe._

    def values[A: c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[A] = {
      val elemType = weakTypeOf[A]
      val elemSymbol = elemType.typeSymbol.asSealedClass
      val elemSymbols = elemSymbol.knownDirectSubclasses.toList
      val elemIdents = elemSymbols.map(s => Ident(s.asCaseClass.asModuleClass.module))
      val elemSeqSymbol = weakTypeOf[Seq[A]].typeSymbol
      c.Expr(Apply(Ident(elemSeqSymbol.companion), elemIdents))
    }

    implicit class SymbolOp(s: Symbol) {
      def asSealedClass = s.asClass.ensuring(_.isSealed, s"$s is not sealed")
      def asCaseClass = s.asClass.ensuring(_.isCaseClass, s"$s is not a case class")
      def asModuleClass = s.asClass.ensuring(_.isModuleClass, s"$s is not an object")
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
object EnumTest extends App {
  sealed trait Foo
  case object Moo extends Foo
  case object Noo extends Foo

  val values = Enum.values[Foo]
  println(values)

  println(Enum.values[Foo])

  println({
    val v = Enum.values[Foo]
    v
  })
}
```

The console should print out three same outputs, but:

```
List()
List(Moo, Noo)
List(Moo, Noo)
```

Wny does this happen? How do you deal with this?
I would appreciate if you can test it in your SBT: https://github.com/ryo0ka/enum

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like an instance of https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Oh thank you for the information :) Can I vote for it or something?

Comment: Glad to help! As for bumping the issue, in any case it's really high on my todo list for scala.meta along with some other fundamental bugs.

Comment: Ok.. thank you for working on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a strange behavior, but it is hard for Scalac to do a good job here: The problem is that you use nested objects. Consider the following:

```
object EnumTest extends App {
  sealed trait Foo
  case object Moo extends Foo
  case object Noo extends Foo

  println(Enum.values[Foo])

  case object Bar extends Foo
}
```

This prints `List(Moo, Noo)`. If we move `Bar` before the `println` statement, it prints `List(Moo, Noo, Bar)` as we would expect.

If we move the sealed hierarchy out of the object, everything works fine.

Therefore, it seems it is probably not a smart idea to have the macro reify at the location where you define your case classes. You could make `values` itself a macro (whose implementation simply calls `Impl.values` with the right `WeakTypeTag`). That would probably work.

Comment: Yes, declaring `value` as macro works, but macro method can't override an abstract method. `def values` works too, but it generates the list every time it's called. So I'm going to imitate this lib: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum whose implementation aims at "enclosing" children. It doesn't gather every child, but `values` can be a `val` that overrides a method, which is finest in my use case. I check your answer because it's one solution which only didn't confirm my requirement that I didn't mention. Thank you so much!!1